# Indicar schema en consulta symfony postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, orm, doctrine

¡Hola a todo el mundo! Después de darle muchas vueltas, no encuentro documentación sobre como especificar el schema de mi bbdd que quiero utilizar a la hora de hacer una consulta a través del ORM de Symfony. Tengo que hacerlo a través de una consulta simple de SQL.
**(Ahora lo hago así)**
EJ:
`'SELECT * FROM schema.contactos'`; (Quiero los contactos de un schema en especifico, no public)

En el resto del proyecto, hago consultas a través del ORM, por ejemplo:
(Búscame un usuario cuyo id sea x)
EJ:

```
$usuario_repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Usuario::class);
    $usuario = $usuario_repo->findOneBy([
        'id' => $id
    ]);
```

En resumen, ¿hay alguna manera de a la hora de consultar por ejemplo, decirle a que schema quiero que acceda desde ORM?

**NOTA: SE QUE DESDE LA ENTIDAD PUEDES HACER @ORM\Table(schema="XXXXXX"), PERO TIENE QUE SER DINAMICO
NOTA2: USO POSTGRESQL**

¡¡GRACIAAAAAS!! :):)

Comment: Puedes definir el `schema` en la entidad, mediante: `schema="nombreDelSchema"`. [Revisa la documentación al respecto](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_table).

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Ya especifico en la pregunta que eso se que se puede hacer. Gracias!